# java class hierarchy getting a string from 2 levels down

Tags: java

i'm a highschool student taking an AP java class through codeHS, iv'e hit a snag and i'm 2 years ahead of the teacher, codeHS is a good site but it doesn't explain everything so here's my problem.

```
public abstract class Solid
{
    private String myName;

    public Solid(String name)
    {
        myName = name;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return myName;
    }

    public abstract double volume();

    public abstract double surfaceArea();
}



public class Cube extends Solid
{

    public int side;

    public Cube(String name, int side)
    {
        super(name);
        this.side = side;
    }

    public double volume()
    {
        return Math.pow(side, 3);
    }

    public double surfaceArea()
    {
        return 6 * Math.pow(side, 2);
    }

}


public class RectangularPrism extends Cube
{
    public int length;
    public int width;
    public int height;

    public RectangularPrism(String name, int width, int height, int length)
    {
        super(name);
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.length = length;
    }


    public double surfaceArea()
    {
        return 2 * (width * length + height * length+ height * width)
    }
}
```

my problem is in the RectangularPrism class, the constructor, it's not grabbing the name from the super class, being cube and i can't/don't know how to store the name from the Solid class into the cube class so i can grab it from there? or is there a way i can grab it from the solid class being inside of the RectangularPrism class

Comment: additional information: i know it will work if i just extend my rectangularPrism class by solid, but the exercise tells me to "extend RectangularPrism with Cube."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `RectangularPrism` class is extended from `Cube` class, however `Cube` class doesn't have a default constructor and it has only one custom constructor. So `RectangularPrism` class must super the constructor, the code is following:

```
public class RectangularPrism extends Cube {

    public int length;
    public int width;
    public int height;

    public RectangularPrism(String name, int width, int height, int length){
        super(name, 0);
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.length = length;
    }


    public double surfaceArea()
    {
        return 2 * (width * length + height * length+ height * width);
    }

    @Override
    public double volume() {
        return (width * length * height);
    }
}
```

Now you can use `getName` method to get the name.

Comment: awesome thanks c:, yeah that's something that wasn't taught in the videos, i'm assuming "super(name, 0)" the 0 refers to the highest class in the hierarchy where as "super(name)" would just refer to one class above, in this case being the cube class

Comment: Thanks for your praise ^_^